# Interference of Ca-EDTA with fluoride delivery in mouthwash

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, drugs

The goal of fluoride mouthwash is to deliver $\ce{F-}$ to the surface of the teeth to turn hydroxyapatite in the dental enamel into fluorapatite.
Typically sodium fluoride or stannous fluoride are used.

*ACT* fluoride mouthwash also contains $\ce{Ca}$ in the form of $\ce{Ca-EDTA}$. 
[image: https://www.drugs.com/otc/114080/act-total-care-anticavity-fluoride-rinse-fresh-min-01.jpg]

$\ce{CaF2}$ has a very low solubiliy product of $3.9 × 10^{−11}$, I would expect the $\ce{F-}$ to precipitate as $\ce{CaF2}$ and become unavailable.
This is in agreement with the literature where $\ce{EDTA}$ has been used in the determination of $\ce{F-}$ through backtitration of $\ce{Ca^2+}$. This shows that the complex is less stable than the fluoride.
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0003267000876369

Note:

It was suggested in the comments to use 10x the concentration of $\ce{Ca-EDTA}$. I don't see how this could work, all it would do is depress the concentration of available fluoride even more.

I suspect $\ce{EDTA}$ is used as an anti biofilm agent or preservative, and the $\ce{Ca}$ is used so it doesn't chelate dental $\ce{Ca}$. I assume this use is unrelated to the process of fluoride delivery.

Comment: Good observation but don't surprised by the fact a lot of food items have EDTA. A mouth-wash is no major exception. You will have read the patent in order to get the idea why EDTA is beneficial in oral rinses https://patents.google.com/patent/WO1988000044A1/en

Comment: Secondly you concern of NaF is not a . Ca-EDTA must be present in excess.

Comment: EDTA suppresses biofilm formation and it also has antimicrobial properties. I assume this is why it as added, or maybe it is used as a preservative. Na-EDTA will scavenge Ca from the teeth, so presumably the Ca-EDTA will leave the Ca in the teeth. What I don't understand is why it does not react with the fluoride.

Comment: think about the concetration. If Ca-EDTA is 10-fold (let us assume) higher conc. than NaF, what do you think about the equilibrium?

Comment: If [Ca-EDTA] is 10x[F-], would not all F- be precipitated as CaF? The other way around we won't have Ca protection against chelation of the Ca in the teeth. If that is the reason they use the Ca salt in the first place.

Comment: There is no $\ce{CaF}$. Presumably you mean $\ce{CaF2}$

Comment: @BuckThorn [calcium subfluoride](http://calcium.atomistry.com/calcium_subfluoride.html) does exist but that isn't relevant here ; ).

Comment: @NilayGhosh Thanks. You learn something new every day, sometimes two things.

Comment: @ Buck Thorn I meant CaF2, fixed the typo. Thanks!